# Prouct price depending upon User IP

Tags: .htaccess, ip

I want to have 2 prices for a product. If user is from India, it should take price-1 and if the user is from out of India, it should take price-2. I just know it will be done through IP basis. But i am not getting how to do it.

Please can somebody suggest me with the rough idea so that i can implement it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do with the following,

1. Product Pricing table with country or region code
2. Geo Data with IP and Country mapping
3. When you pull data map these two tables and get the results.The relations and mapping purely on the level of layers your having for the pricing
4. You can create the view for joining geo and product price table and
   query the view to get a result.
5. If data not getting changed frequently load the data in cache or
   server/   DB. This will improve the performance

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You could try getting a range of IP addresses that are assigned to India.

http://www.ipaddresslocation.org/ip_ranges/get_ranges.php

Then check the visitor's IP address against the list. This isn't fool proof though. An Indian visitor could visit your site through a VPN or non-Indian based proxy.

You may consider enforcing the price at checkout time once they enter their billing information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what language you are building this in, however you would need to use some sort of geolocation lookup api to cross check the client ip address against the country.

You can look at using something like: http://ip-api.com/docs/api:json

Comment: I am doing it in PHP (Opencart)